# BorderLayout.CENTER doesn't center

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

I can't get my JLabel to center in my JPanel after adding a ChartPanel to it:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());            
panel.add(visualiser(ternaire), BorderLayout.NORTH);//visualiser(ternaire) is the ChartPanel
panel.add(new JLabel("L'alliage a bien été enregistré."), BorderLayout.CENTER);
JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();            
jop.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Information", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Any idea why BorderLayout.CENTER doesn't work ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`JLabel` by default is horizontally aligned to the left.

You need to set the `horizontalAlignment` to be `JLabel.CENTER`

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JLabel label = new JLabel("L'alliage a bien été enregistré.");
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't center your JLabel, it puts it toe the left side (I think). You need to change the alignment of the JLabel.